# TeXstudio Not Responding

Tags: texstudio, mac

The TeXstudio on my Mac doesn't work since about half a year ago (it worked well before, and I really liked its auto-fill feature), and always showing *Not Responding* in my activity monitor, the memory it uses can fast explode to more than 10GB.
[image]

Here is a portion I got after clicking reporting to TeXstudio:
[image]
Can anyone tell what's my problem, and how can I resolve it? I can provide more detail if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want to report it in https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/, directly to TeXstudio maintainers.

Comment: First questions first. Your screenshot tells you are using an up-to-date MacOS version and an up-to-date TeXStudio 64bit version. **BUT** what about the TeX engine you're using? Do you use TeXLive or MikTeX? Does this error also occurs when you create a simple `Hello World` tex file?

Comment: Around July 2022 a major update on some core LaTeX - especially LaTeX 3 - files was distributed, resulting in some critical errors in older / unmaintained packages as code was changed. That might coincide with your problem too.

Comment: @alchemist Thank you! I have MacTeX on my Mac (I'm not sure the TeX engine I'm using, I think I don't use TeXLive or MikTeX).

Comment: @Lao-tzu You can check on the TeX engine quite easily: open `TeXStudio` - go to `Help` - click on `LaTeX Reference ...` . A report will be printed in a new window, giving a lot of information about your TeX environment.

Comment: @alchemist The problem is, I can't even open TeXStudio, Not Responding....

Comment: Oops ...  Did you delete the installation, restarted you Mac a few times and the reinstalled TeXStudio? Sounds the obvious thing to do, but one has to ask it too. Sometimes the registry isn't cleared of all references to a program when it is deleted, Occurs mostly after just updating an existing installation.

Comment: No, the Mac I'm using is a new one (got 4mo ago). I migrated all softwares from my previous Mac. The TeXStudio had problem already on my previous Mac (during which time I used TeXShop instead, but it's slow, no auto-fill feature), I indeed deleted the installation, restarted Mac a few times and the reinstalled TeXStudio.

Comment: Have you tried to delete all local TeXstudio configuration files of the user? Alternatively you could add a new user, login with the new user and try if TeXstudio starts. If it does there is a problem with the user settings of your standard user. If it doesn't it is a more general problem.

Comment: BTW: MacTeX is TeX Live with some additions for Mac.

Comment: No idea if it might help, but a newer texstudio version is available at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/download/4.5.1/texstudio-4.5.1-osx.dmg (I recently had a problem with texstudio getting unresponsive due to some edge case in syntax highlighting when I opened the source of the pgfpages package; an update solved this for me)

Comment: You could also try if something in your configuration might cause the problem: close texstudio, rename the folder `~/.config/texstudio/` to something else and then try to open texstudio again

Comment: @alchemist The tex distribution does not have any influence on the actual program of texstudio. You could happily use it as an text editor even without having a tex distribution installed.

Comment: @cabohah Yes, thanks! I found "TeX Live Utility" in MacTeX. I deleted my TeXstudio and MacTeX, and reinstalled (but not sure if there were things remaining). I'll add a new user to see if it works.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I checked, the newer texstudio version has same problem as before.

Comment: @Lao-tzu As muzimuzhi Z said in the first comment, report it to https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/

Comment: @cabohah I added a new user and it indeed works. So there is a problem with the user settings, but I don't know how to find the problem. If I make the new user as another Admin, and delete the original user (Admin), would I lose anything in my Mac?

Comment: @Lao-tzu If the configuration of the user is the problem, delete or rename it. With Linux/Unix/Mac this should be `~/.config/texstudio` (note: `~` is a shorthand for the home directory of the user). With Windows it would be `%APPDATA%\texstudio`. So you don't need to completely switch to a new user. The new user was only for testing.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks! I don't know how to rename configuration, can you tell?

Comment: Just rename `~/.config/texstudio` for example in `~/.config/nottexstudio`. You can do this either in the GUI or from a terminal window using: `rm ~/.config/texstudio `~/.config/nottexstudio`. BTW: Renaming a file or directory is not a TeX problem, but a OS question and should be asked in the corresponding forum.

Comment: @cabohah Thank you very much!